# Evalute derivative of $g\left(x\right)=\int _{200}^{2x}\:\:\left(t^4-14\right)^{200}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

Having hard time understanding this question.

$g\left(x\right)=\int _{200}^{2x}\:\:\left(t^4-14\right)^{200}dt$

then $g'\left(1\right)=?$

Would I just plus 1 into the function? Is there some kind of trick?

Answer (score 4):

Note that by the fundamental theorem of calculus, the function 
$$ G(y) = \int_{200}^{y} (t^4 - 14)^{200} \, dt $$
has the derivative 
$$ G'(y) = (y^4 - 14)^{200} $$
Your function $g$ is given by $g(x) = G(2x)$, hence the chain rule gives 
$$ g'(x) = 2 \cdot G'(2x) $$
that is 
$$ g'(1) = 2 \cdot G'(2) = 2 \cdot (16 - 14)^{200} = 2^{201}. $$

Answer (score 0):

Let be $f(t)=(t^4-14)^{200}$ and $F(t)=\int_0^tf(\tau)d\tau$ one primitive function.
So $g(x)=F(2x)-F(200)\implies g'(x)=2f(2x)\implies g'(1)=2(16-14)^{200}=2^{201}$